# Youtube Video View Count

Tags: caching, youtube

If you notice, the Number of Views of an Youtube video doesn't change if you refresh the video page multiple times.

Also if you open up the same url on a different browser from same computer it still shows old count.

Any guess what can be their logic of maintaining this view count?

Do they have 2 count fields and they sync up nightly and page always show the synced value not the count that gets updated with page refresh?

Thanks

Comment: i think they dont let video count jump because this increases the popularity of some violent videos or videos that don't follow the terms and conditions of their website i.e. porn

Comment: Further, I would guess, they increase the counter only when you actually watched the video (e.g. more than 90% of the timeline processed in normal speed, not jumping), not by just requesting the surrounding website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they record all page views which increments the counter, but the output (the HTML you receive) is cached - or at least that portion of it is.

It makes sense - Youtube is a very popular website serving many concurrent people. Performance is very important.

Comment: I like this answer as the best. Reason: as you said, it makes the most sense though might not be the most accurate count.

Comment: Checking against IP address OR Wait for 10 mins or whole hour seems stupid. If I click a video, I might leave the page if I don't like it. But still I viewed it.

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense not to increase the view count if you keep refreshing the page in your browser, or even opening the page in another browser on the same computer. This can be done by recording the IP of your computer and storing it for a given time interval: the view count will increase only once in that interval. So from a given computer(identified by IP, maybe) the view count of a clip will only increase once per hour/day/etc...

Comment: Page refresh can be detected. So it can be prevented to increase the counter if it is a page refresh.

Comment: Increasing the counter should be prevented no matter how the page is accessed from the same computer in the given interval, so whether it is a page refresh or something else is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, what exactly does the user have to do in order for the site to consider it a "view" is another story(maybe you have to actually watch the clip more that 50% or whatever), but the "view" will only be considered as valid just once per time interval.